# Удаление текста по клику в диве

Tags: javascript, jquery, события

Есть отправка сообщений. Она работает, но когда я отправляю сообщение, текст в диве остается. Как сделать так, чтобы при клике на кнопку "отправить" в поле
ввода удалялся текст.[image: Текст до отправки]

[image: По клику текст остается в поле ввода]

Comment: Код, код ваш покажите и ваши попытки, а не скриншоты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.MyButton').on('click', function() {
    $("div.MyInput").html("");
});
```

Comment: `.empty()` для этого есть